# CURL used in shell

Tags: unix, shell-script

I am executing a shell script in which one curl command is present. I have to store the output of curl command(xml format) in a file and display the result on screen. For this to happen "tee command" is used after curl using pipeline. I need to check if the curl command is executing successfully or not. I used $? but it is taking the exit status of tee command. 
I used PIPESTATUS[0] and set -o pipefail but did not work for curl.
How do i check if the curl command is executing successfully or not? How do I store the exit status of curl command in a variable?
This is just a demo code.

`curl output | tee -a filename`

I want to know the exit status of curl

Answer (score 1):

Use the $PIPESTATUS var which is an array. Following will give you the return code of the piped command.

```
curl output | tee -a filename
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

Comment: +1, but requires a **bash warning**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following construction:

```
content=`curl http://www.google.com`
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then 
  # do some fail stuff
else
  echo '$content' | tee /tmp/output.file
fi
```

It stores the output of curl in a variable, then checks the exit status, and if it's successful, tee the output to a file (and stdout).

Comment: echo? no quotes? on something received from network? seriously? -1.

Comment: @JanHudec You're right about the quotes, I assumed he is going to pull something from a page he trusts (I edited the post). You're more than welcome to edit my answer so we can all learn from your wisdom